# MongoDB C# Driver: Execute Database Method through the SDK?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to be able to execute a [database method](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/js-database/) using the C# SDK (2.2.4). Take `db.version()` for example.

I've tried to play around with `Database.RunCommand`, but with no luck:

```
var command = new BsonDocumentCommand<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument
{
    { "version", 1 }
});

var versionResult = Database.RunCommand(command);
```

Exception:

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command version failed: no such
>   command: 'version', bad cmd: '{ version: 1 }'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not always a direct mapping between the shell database methods you link to and the underlying database commands that are available via `Database.RunCommand`. The available commands are listed [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/), and to get the server version you could use the [`serverStatus`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#dbcmd.serverStatus) command:

```cs
var version = db.RunCommand<dynamic>(new BsonDocument("serverStatus", 1)).version;
```

Answer (score 1):

I can get dbstats using above approach but not version. (in both mongo shell and .net)

But then I get same error if i try to get version this way in mongo shell

```
db.runCommand({version:1})
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "no such command: 'version', bad cmd: '{ version: 1.0 }'",
    "code" : 59
}
```

There seems to be different way to get version? as runCommand supports operations which are supported on Mongo shell?